# Start out processing in ASP.NET once the page has been loaded and displayed

Tags: asp.net

I have an ASP.Net application that uses a MasterPage.  I have one page which includes two panels whose visibility is set dependent on the postback arguments to the page.  In one condition I want some processing to occur but only after the whole page has been loaded as the panel will show a loading panel.

Ideally I wish to start this processing from code behind.  Is this possible to do after the page is displayed?

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what kind of "processing" you mean, but it sounds like what you want is to kick off a background thread after the page has finished its life-cycle.  You can offload the processing to a [background worker thread](http://www.dotneat.net/2009/02/10/BackgroundworkerExample.aspx) (so it's outside the page life-cycle and not a blocking process for the web application), and kick off that thread from the [page's Unload event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.unload.aspx).